# Probability of an aleatory experiment conducted $n$ times

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random, primality-test

What is the probability of an aleatory experiment conducted $n$ times?
For example, say we choose randomly a number $x$ from a known interval, which happens to contain some certain kind of numbers we're going to call *Specifics*. So, if we know that the size of the set containing all the Specifics is half the size of the entire interval, the probability must be:
$$P(S) = \frac{N(S)}{N(Ω)} = \frac{1}{2}$$
So, if we choose to go with $n$ different random $x$-es, is the probability $P(S)^n$? If so, why?

Comment: Shouldn't that just be a binomial distribution?

Comment: @404UserNotFound how do you mean?

Comment: Do you want the probability of all $n$ $x$'s satisfying the condition, or that of at least one $x$ out of the $n$ draws satisfying the condition?

Comment: @mzp at least one $x$ out of the $n$ draws, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p \equiv P(S)$. The probability of all $n$ draws satisfying the condition is, in fact, $p^n$.

The probability of exactly $k$ out of the $n$ draws satisfying the condition is given by

$$\binom n k  p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

In particular, the probability of exactly $1$ success is given by

$$ \binom n 1  p(1-p)^{n-1}$$

Finally the probability of at least one success is equal $1$ minus the probability of missing every draw,

$$1-p^n $$

Comment: thanks a lot. So, is $P = {{n}\choose{k}}p^k(1 - p)^{n-k}$ easy to prove? How do you prove it?

Comment: @jimkokko5 This is the Binomial distribution. Suppose $k=1$. Then ${{n}\choose{1}} =n$ is the number of ways you could get one success: in the first draw, in the second draw, an so on. $p^1(1 - p)^{n-1}$ is the probability of getting one success and $n-1$ failures. Multiplying the two you get the probability of one success. The logic is similar for $k \neq 1 $.